# std::cout using ' ' implitations - Dont understand the output

Tags: c++, casting, operators, std, stdout

I'm a complete novice in C++, trying to migrate from C to this new language, but using the new things it has to offer. Thanks for the support

---

**The question is, easy and direct, what does the ' ' do in the std::cout?**

```
#include "includes.h"

int main( ){

    char c1 = 'x', c2;
    int i1 = c1 , i2 = 'x';

    c2 = i1;

    std::cout << c1 <<'<< i1 <<'<< c2 <<'\n';

}
```

---

I copied this code from Bjarne Stroustrup Book ("Programming Principles and Practice using C++" second edition) and did minor differences. In it, he said the output was going to be x 120 x or x120x (my eyes don`t catch the difference from the print), which is not the case.

Comment: You copied that code rather badly unless Bjarne was intoxicated when he wrote it :-) Suggest you re-check and edit.

Comment: Shouldn&#39;t it be double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: Haha, looking at it right now, and not major changes. 
the original code is this
    char c = 'x';
    int i1 = c;
    int i2 = 'x';

    char c2 = i1;

    cout << c <<'<< i1 <<'<<c2 <<'\n';


I'm going towards the intoxication. But still, no idea what are the consequences of this use?

Comment: You must be missing something. Those are probably supposed to be `' '`, two single quotes with a space between them, not just one single quote. That's to put a space between `x` and `120`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looke like there's either a printing problem in the book or you copied it wrong. It probably should be:

```
std::cout << c1 << ' ' << i1 << ' ' << c2 <<'\n';
```

`' '` is a single space character, so this will put spaces around the number in `i1`. It prints:

```
x 120 x
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/nPcST8)

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are meant to *surround* **one** character literal. Like:

```
'A' 'C' 'x' ' ' '5' etc.
```

Single quotes `'` are not meant to surround a string literal (which consists of multiple character literals) so it is wrong to do:

```
`Hello World`
```

Or in your case:

```
'<< i1 <<'
```

So the rule of thumb is: when having a char literal surround it with single quotes `'a'`, when dealing with string literal surround it with double quotes: `"Some string 123"`.
If you are simply trying to print out the `i2` variable then use:

```
std::cout << c1 << i1 << c2 << '\n';
```

**Update:**
There are exceptions to the rule. Some implementations support wrapping a multicharacter literal in single quotes.

> A multicharacter literal has type int and implementation-deﬁned value.

6.4.4.4/10 in C11 specification has more info on the subject.

Comment: I don't think he really meant to print a string there. He must have copied something wrong, and there should be some char literals to the left and right of `i1`.

Comment: There can be multiple characters inside single quotes, the behaviour is implementation-defined

Comment: @M.M Appreciate. I have updated the answer as per your input.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand difference between `'a'` and `"a"`.

`'a'` is a character literal. It's of type `char`, with the value 97 on most systems (the ASCII/Latin-1/Unicode encoding for the letter `a`).

`"a"` is a string literal.  It's of type `const char[2]`, and refers to an array of 2 `char`s with values `'a'` and `'\0'`. In most, but not all, contexts, a reference to `"a"` will be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first character of the string.

Both

```
cout << 'a';
```

and

```
cout << "a";
```

happen to produce the same output, but for different reasons. The first prints a single character value. The second successively prints all the characters of the string (except for the terminating `'\0'`) -- which happens to be the single character `'a'`.

String literals can be arbitrarily long, such as `"abcdefg"`. Character literals almost always contain just a single character. (You can have *multicharacter literals*, such as `'ab'`, but their values are implementation-defined and they're very rarely useful.)

(In C, which you didn't ask about, `'a'` is of type `int`, and `"a"` is of type `char[2]` (no `const`)).

So, in your case type code like this : `'<< i1 <<'` is a character literal. `char`